# CSS doesn't apply to a component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mobx

I have a react component that is wrapped up in div:

AccountLogin.jsx:

```
import './AccountLogin.css';
export default observer(() => (
  <div className="content">
    Something here
  </div>
));
```

AccountLogin.css:

```
.content {
  color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 500px;
}
```

But the css doesn't apply to my rendered component AccountLogin.

Any ideas why that could happen?

Comment: Is class content already defined somewhere else?

Comment: As in the styles does not appear to be in the definition of the div? or is it getting overridden by something?

Comment: @Johnny_H I changed it to other custom string but it didn't help.

Comment: Does the component actually render?  I don't see a `render` method.

Comment: @Huangism I see the rendered content and the margin doesn't apply, I don't know if it is getting overriden or just doesn't apply.

Comment: if you are inspecting and see the rules, scroll down and see if there is a margin overriding it. Only margin doesn't work and everything else does? Are you able to reproduce this in http://jsfiddle.net ? Could you paste the output html instead of what you have

Comment: If this AccountLogin.jsx is imported in another component which's parent also has className does it override the child className and its css?

Comment: Can you share your webpack config ? It is likely that your webpack is configured to use css modules.

Comment: @lorefnon https://pastebin.com/kVw7Ns6m
Found two webpack configs, pasted them both in here as I don't know which one do you need and how they differ.

Comment: Did you use any boilerplate to setup your project ?

Comment: @lorefnon I am using rfx stack but I don't think it is related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [rfx-stack source](https://github.com/foxhound87/rfx-stack/blob/40818adb852122c178baa745d71326b25dc0e9fa/webpack/loaders.js), I can see that files suffixed with `.global.css` are imported in global scope where as others are imported as [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

So you can either rename your file to `AccountLogin.global.css` or use the imported class name:

```
import styles from './AccountLogin.css';

Within component: 
<div className={styles.content}>...</div>
```

Comment: That was fast by you, appreciate the help fellow developer!